# Why is my WP Query not returning first result's post meta?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, advanced-custom-fields

I am a creating a shortcode to return posts from a custom post type, along with specific ACF fields. Everything is working fine except for the first post not returning it's post meta info.

My code:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'show',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key'  => 'show_date',
    'order' => ASC
);

$output = '';

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $query->have_posts() ){

    $output .= '<h1>The Showlist</h1>';

    while( $query->have_posts() ){

        $show_date = get_field('show_date');
        $show_venue = get_field('show_venue');

        // print '<pre>';
        // print_r($show_date);
        // print '</pre>';

        $query->the_post();
        $output .= '<h3>' . get_the_title() . ' @ <a href="/venue/' . $show_venue->post_name . '">' . $show_venue->post_title . '</a></h3>';
        $output .= '<p>' . $show_date . '</p>';
    }

}
wp_reset_postdata();

// do shortcode actions here
return $output;
```

An example of what I am getting:

- Showlist Title -
- Showlist Title - Show Venue - Show Date
- Showlist Title - Show Venue - Show Date
- Showlist Title - Show Venue - Show Date
- Showlist Title - Show Venue - Show Date
- Showlist Title - Show Venue - Show Date
- Showlist Title - Show Venue - Show Date

I am not sure why the first item is not returning the meta info. I have double check that it does contain the information in the backend.

Any ideas? TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    $show_date = get_field('show_date');
    $show_venue = get_field('show_venue');

    // print '<pre>';
    // print_r($show_date);
    // print '</pre>';

    $query->the_post();
```

You are setting the active post AFTER getting the values.

Put `$query->the_post()` always at the top of that while loop, so that the other functions can rely on the global $post variable being set correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much, I knew it had to be something simple that I overlooked.